# HANA Spatial: Query by Circle (Center and Radius)

Tags: spatial, hana

Using [SAP HANA Spatial](http://help.sap.com/hana/SAP_HANA_Spatial_Reference_en.pdf), how do I query for all the points contained within a circle? Ideally, I would like to specify the latitude and longitude of the center, as well as the radius.

For instance, select all landmarks around 'Berlin - Alexanderplatz' (52.5219184 13.4132147) in a radius of 10 kilometers.

PS. To try it out:

1. Register an account on https://account.hanatrial.ondemand.com and log in.
2. Create a Database: Open *Databases & Systems* under *Persistence*. Click *New*, enter a *Database ID*, select **HANA MDC (<trial>)** as *Database System*, enter a *SYSTEM User Password*, and save.
3. Open the Development Tools: In the overview of your database, click *SAP HANA Web-based Development Workbench* and log in with the SYSTEM user. Under *Security*, grant the application privilege **sap.hana.ide::Catalog** to the user *SYSTEM*. (Yes I know, don't do this in real life!). Open the *Catalog*.
4. Create a database table: Click the button *Open SQL Console (Command-Alt-C)*, enter the following SQL code and click the *Run (F8)* button.

   ```
   CREATE COLUMN TABLE "COORDINATES" ("LOCATION_NAME" VARCHAR(100), "COORDINATE" ST_POINT(0) CS_POINT);
   INSERT INTO "COORDINATES" VALUES ('Berlin - Brandenburger Tor', NEW ST_Point('POINT(52.5162746 13.377704)'));
   INSERT INTO "COORDINATES" VALUES ('Berlin - Gendarmenmarkt', NEW ST_Point('POINT(52.5137224 13.3926698)'));
   INSERT INTO "COORDINATES" VALUES ('Paris - Tour Eiffel', NEW ST_Point('POINT(48.8583701 2.2944813)'));
   ```
5. To query by rectangle, fire the following statement.

   ```
   SELECT LOCATION_NAME, COORDINATE.ST_ASGEOJSON() FROM COORDINATES WHERE (NEW ST_Polygon('Polygon((52 13, 52 14, 53 14, 53 13, 52 13))').ST_Contains(COORDINATE)) = 1;
   ```
6. But, remember, I need a circle! How can I retrieve the same results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wouldn't that be the case that the distance between your circle center point and your objects need to be smaller than the radius?
Something like

```
SELECT LOCATION_NAME, COORDINATE.ST_ASGEOJSON() 
FROM COORDINATES 
WHERE 
COORDINATE.ST_Distance( NEW ST_Point('POINT(52.5162746 13.377704)')) <= 2;
```

Here I just put the coordinates for the Brandenburger Tor and the radius of 2 - but you should get the picture.